# array separate array ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, haml, loops, enumerator

i have the following code which is meant to be looping over an array, with a comma after each object expect the last idea

```
-if is_manager(team)
   - is_manager(team).map(&:fullname).each.join(',') do |name|
   = "#{name}"
```

it appears that the code is trying to be executed, but for some reason the .join element is causing it to error like below

```
undefined method `join' for #<Enumerator: ["Tom Garcia", "Paul McGuane"]:each>
```

what do i need to do, to have this working?

Comment: Been a while since I tried Ruby, but should the `each` really be there?

Comment: Not sure if it will be relevant but http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/CoreExtensions/Array/Conversions/to_sentence may be useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
-if is_manager(team)
   = is_manager(team).map(&:fullname).join(',')
```

Comment: See my edited answer for comment about there being no output.

Comment: Eek, I had written that when Paul commented saying there was no output - sorry if my comment lost context!

Comment: Yeah, changed the `-` to `=` for output

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the "each" piece; join is to be called on an array directly and should return a string.

Meaning the following should suffice:

```
is_manager(team).map(&:fullname).join(',')
```

Edit: Seems you're using HAML, so you need the '=' for output, try the following:

```
-if is_manager(team)
   = is_manager(team).map(&:fullname).join(',')
```

Comment: thanks DRobinson, i picked that up after posting, hence the deletation :)